# Which photography movements do these images fit?

Tags: image-processing

I have to take 3 photos for an assignment that emulate historical and modern photo movements and I took a bunch of photos and I don’t know which photo falls under what movement. Can you help? The movements are:

a) Pictorialism

b) straight photography

c) futurism

d) constructivism

e) dada and surrealism

f) fashion photography

g) photojournalism

h) documentary photography

i) abstract photography

j) street photography.

Obviously I know the photos don’t qualify under certain movements but I just thought to put all the movements I’ve learnt about just for no reason in particular.

Hoping someone could help. Thank u!!

Image one:

[image: image one]

Image two:

[image: image two]

Image three:

[image: image three]

Comment: What movement **do you think** your image is closest to?

Comment: I think futurism but not too sure

Comment: Let me get this straight, you had an assignment to photograph x, y, and z and instead of looking up the definitions of x, y, and z you instead run out with a camera and take your best shot at it? I think you missed the goal of the assignment.

Comment: Seems more like this is a test question and you’re trying to get answers to it...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo-SE. Unfortunately, as written, your question (and the other two identical copy/paste questions) doesn't really fit the format of [what's acceptable here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Specifically, you're just asking people to pick a letter from the list you provided, without providing any criteria for what you're looking for. Furthermore, the items in the list aren't particularly mutually-exclusive, which means the answers are likely to be primarily **opinion-oriented**.

Comment: Please take a quick look at the brief [Site Tour](https:/photo.stackexchange.com/tour) to get an idea of how the site works, and types of questions and answers we look for here. After that, please edit your question to be more focused. For instance, you said you think your image would be most closely considered as "futurism". Why? What aspects of your image fall into that category. Is that what you were trying to convey when you took the photo? Are there similar photos you've seen, that are futuristic like that? Provide us some concrete details about your goal, and we might be able to answer.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a request for help with a class assignment, which is perfectly acceptable here. But rather than tell you which movement each photo may fit into, I'm going to try and help you better do the assignment yourself, okay?

The way you've done it is putting the cart before the horse, so to speak. You've taken a few random images and now you wish to fit them into a specific category.

The best way to complete such an assignment would be to study each of the photographic movements until you understand what, exactly, makes an image fit into a particular movement. Once you understand that, you can go out and shoot an image with the specific purpose of creating an image that demonstrates the qualities that define the particular movement in question.

For instance, let's look at *futurism*:

- Futurism was an early 20th century art movement centered in Italy that emphasized the dynamism, speed, energy, and power of the machine and the vitality, change, and restlessness of modern life. In paintings it often relied on Cubism, which was an already emerging movement when futurism began. Of course *cubism* showed different parts of a subject from different viewpoints or perspectives. But a single image from a stationary camera can only have a single perspective.
- Futurist photographic techniques include the layering of multiple negatives, perspectival foreshortening, and photomontage. These techniques allowed photographs to examine their subjects from different perspectives in a different way than Cubist paintings did. Futurist photos tended to show human subjects in motion, either blurred by long exposures or by combining a sequence of shorter exposures to show the subject as they moved.

To create a photograph that emulates the *futurist* movement, you could take a burst of photos of a person running across a room, or playing a cello, or bouncing a ball, etc. and then combine the exposures into a single image. Or you could use a darkened room and a stroboscopic flash capable of [multiple bursts during a single exposure](https://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-use-multi-flash-to-capture-compelling-action-photos/) to show the same thing. This capability is called [*Multi*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16339/15871) or [*Stroboscopic*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43361/15871) or [*Repeating*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26997/15871) flash.

**The point is, you should be deciding what movement you want a photograph to fit in *before* you take it and work to create a photograph that fits the characteristics of that movement.**